# MVC Required Field not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, required

Title says it all, can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong. I've tried moving around my HTMlValidation Summary and a bunch of other things. I feel like it may have something to with the views I am returning from my Controller Class.

```
-- Model
 public class Login
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "First Namex")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Passwordx")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

  -- Controller
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string FirstName, string Password)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool validLogin = new UserBAL().ValidateUser(FirstName, Password);
            {
                if (validLogin == true)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Invoice");
                }
                else
                {
                  return RedirectToAction("Index");
                  //  ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }

 --View 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home"))  
{ @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div>
    <fieldset>   
        <legend>Login</legend>       
        <div class ="fields">              
          @Html.LabelFor(u => u.FirstName)
          </div>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.FirstName)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.FirstName)  <br />       

        <div class ="fields">            
         @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>
         @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password) <br />                 
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

}

---

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(EIAS.Models.Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool validLogin = new UserBAL().ValidateUser(login);
            {
            if (validLogin == true)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Invoice");
                }
                else
                {
                  return RedirectToAction ("Index");
                  //  ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

MVC in `if (ModelState.IsValid)` validate the model, and you don't receive the model in your action:

```
public ActionResult Login(string FirstName, string Password)
```

change the parameters of the action to:

```
public ActionResult Login(Login model)
```

and, for validate in the client, check if:

- if you include jquery validate plugin (js)
- check your web.config, keys `ClientValidationEnabled` and `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` ir are in true.

[check this link](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/bcWO151212-How-to-Enable-and-Disable-Client-Side-Validation-in-MVC.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the Model as the parameter to your Login action

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    // This will return the view with the form that you have above
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Login login)
{
    // this is what your form will post too
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        bool validLogin = new UserBAL().ValidateUser(login.FirstName, login.Password);
        {
            if (validLogin == true)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Invoice");
            }
            else
            {
              return RedirectToAction("Index");
              //  ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

In the View just have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

Here is a link about MVC Razor Forms: http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/

Try that.

Comment: ok, then How can I pass the textbox values to my business layer function since it takes 2 arguements, firstname and password

Comment: yes I made it ValidateUser(login) and passed it through the layers like that before being able to use login."FIeld"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my Views and which views I was returning. I was trying to use my Index view for validation, I hadn't created a Login View, so once I did that and added my validation to the Login View it worked. So in my question, Return View() wasn't really returning anything